# How can I adjust the socket data length to be flexible?

Tags: sockets, go, tcp

```
d := make([]byte, 4096)
conn.Read(d)
```

I created a fixed array to get data from the socket.

But I want to get the data in a flexible size rather than a fixed size.

The reason is that i need to unmarshal the data received from the socket, but the data is fixed in size, so calling the unmarshal function will not work.

So what I want to ask is how to get the data from the socket in a flexible size or how to delete empty values ​​from a fixed size.

```
ex)
data := make([]byte, 4096)
conn.Read(data)
fmt.Println(len(data)) ===> 105 (Actual data length)

or

data([4, 128, 16, 8, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 9, 128, 0...])

↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓

data([4, 128, 16, 8, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 9, 128])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example,

```
data := make([]byte, 0, 4096)

n, err := conn.Read(data[:cap(data)])
data = data[:n]
if err != nil {
    // handle error
}

fmt.Println(len(data))
```